# Hide/show div not working in IE7

Tags: jquery, wordpress, internet-explorer-7

I have taken over a WordPress site that uses jquery to show/hide content in a frame when clicking a link in a another div.  This works perfectly in all browsers except IE7. In IE7, nothing happens. Nothing at all.  And it doesn't throw any errors.
Here is the code I'm using

HTML:

```
<div id="campaignCards" class="contentBody">
<?php $args = array( 
   'post_type' => 'home_promos', 
   'posts_per_page' => 8,
   'order' =>'ASC' );
     $postcount = 0;
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
     <a class="slideLink" href="<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID,     
         'mcb2b_home_promos_link', true)) { echo get_post_meta($post->ID,   
         'mcb2b_home_promos_link', true); } ?>">
     <div class="campaign_card" id="card<?php echo $postcount; ?>">
       <?php the_content();?>
     </div>
     </a>
      <? $postcount++; endwhile; ?> 
</div>          
<div id="homebuttons">
<ul>
    <?php $args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'home_promos', 
    'posts_per_page' => 8,
    'order' =>'ASC' );
      $postcount = 0;
       $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
       while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
    <li class="campaignPicker">
       <a href="javascript:showonlyone('card<?php echo $postcount; ?>');">
            <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) {the_post_thumbnail();} ?>
       </a>
    </li>
      <?php  $postcount++; endwhile; ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
      var campaign_card = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
            for(var x=0; x<campaign_card.length; x++) {
                  name = campaign_card[x].getAttribute("class");
                  if (name == 'campaign_card') {
                        if (campaign_card[x].id == thechosenone) {
                        campaign_card[x].style.display = 'block';
                  }
                  else {
                        campaign_card[x].style.display = 'none';
                  }
            }
      }
}
```

I think the problem is in the `var campaign_card = document.getElementsByTagName("div");` but I'm not proficient with jquery to debug in IE.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Showing a sample of the rendered html would be more helpful in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your code does not seem to use jQuery at all. If you want to use the power of jquery I suggest you to read the tutorials [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials).

Anyway, for your problem you want to try this:

```
function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
  $(".campaign_card").hide();
  $("#" + thechosenone).show();
}
```

Comment: I am using jquery for other functions in the site, as I mentioned I took it over and didn't build that function originally. I apologize for the mis-speak.  This was exactly what I was after, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
  $('div#' + thechoenone).css('display', 'block');
  $('div.campaign_card').css('display', 'none');
}
```

Try this instead of your function. Note, you need to ensure you've included the jQuery library as part of your project.